# Postgresql : issue with two unnest inside one query

Tags: postgresql

I have one table about IT network with these columns :

-gid is the id

-cableA contains a list of wires with cat4 sort separated with '+' and have geom

-cableB contains a list of wires with cat5 sort separated with '+' and have geom

-cableC contains a list of wires with cat6 sort separated with '+' and have geom

-secondC contains details about each item and the switch they come from

-geom is where items are

My current script :

```
create table a(gid integer
           , cableA varchar
           , cableB varchar
           , cableC varchar
           , secondC varchar,
           geom varchar);

-- These wires have 197 as id, no wire of typeA, one wire of typeB, one wire of typeC, origin not present, g1 as geom
INSERT INTO a(gid, cableA, cableB, cableC, secondC, geom) VALUES 
(197
 , ''
 , 'A'
 , 'B'
 , ''
 , 'G1');
-- These wires have 2 as id, two wires of typeA, one wire of typeB, one wire of typeC, Origin of F is A/ Origin of G is B/ Origin of A is A/ Origin of B is A, g2 as geom
INSERT INTO a(gid, cableA, cableB, cableC, secondC, geom) VALUES (2
 , 'F+G'
 , 'A'
 , 'B'
 , 'A+B+A+A'
 , 'G2');

-- These wires have 3 as id, 3 wires of typeA, one wire of typeB, one wire of typeC, Origin of U is A/ Origin of V is B/ Origin of W is A/ Origin of A is A/ Origin of B is A, g3 as geom
INSERT INTO a(gid, cableA, cableB, cableC, secondC, geom) VALUES (3
 , 'U+V+W'
 , 'A'
 , 'B'
 , 'A+B+A+A+A'
 , 'G3')
```

This is my query :

```
select 
  gid,
  unnest(string_to_array(a.CableC,'+')) as split1,
  case when a.secondC is not null 
  then unnest(string_to_array(a.secondC,'+')) else '' end as split2,
  geom
from a
where cableC = 'B'

--I want and need
-- 197 / NULL / G1 because the secondC string is empty
-- 2 / A / G2 because 4th position in secondC
-- 3 / A / G3 because 5th position in secondC
```

The aim is to get all GX and origin linked to a wire. I don't know how to keep the position inside the secondC column and get the right switch.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *because 4th position in secondC ... because 5th position in secondC* - it's not clear. Do you want do get the last letter in `secondC`?

Comment: For the id 2, there are 4 wire letters F,G,A,B so in order inside the A+B+A+A , A is the 4th position like the B letter. Numbers of letters and switch id are equals.

Comment: No, I want the letter at the position when you sum typeA+typeB+typeC. If there are 5 items in total 3+2+1 and the wire is in the last type, and A+A+A+A+B, the result is B

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `unnest()`. First, convert all `cables` as well as `secondc` to arrays:

```
select 
    gid, 
    string_to_array(format('%s+%s+%s', cablea, cableb, cablec), '+') as cables,
    string_to_array(secondc, '+') as secondc,
    geom
from a

 gid |   cables    |   secondc   | geom 
-----+-------------+-------------+------
 197 | {"",A,B}    | {}          | G1
   2 | {F,G,A,B}   | {A,B,A,A}   | G2
   3 | {U,V,W,A,B} | {A,B,A,A,A} | G3
(3 rows)
```

Next, get the position of 'B' in `cables` and find the corresponding element in `secondc`:

```
select 
    gid,
    secondc[array_position(cables, 'B')],
    geom
from (
    select 
        gid, 
        string_to_array(format('%s+%s+%s', cablea, cableb, cablec), '+') as cables,
        string_to_array(secondc, '+') as secondc,
        geom
    from a
    ) s

 gid | secondc | geom 
-----+---------+------
 197 |         | G1
   2 | A       | G2
   3 | A       | G3
(3 rows)
```

Read about [Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful query, is it possible to make the 'B' value as param like this :     select 
    gid,
    secondc[array_position(cables, cableCurrent)],
    geom
from (
    select 
        gid, cablec as cableCurrent
        string_to_array(format('%s+%s+%s', cablea, cableb, cablec), '+') as cables,
        string_to_array(secondc, '+') as secondc,
        geom
    from a
    ) s . I know that the right column to look in the subquery

Comment: Of course, this `B` can be a parameter. There is no difference between parameters in `SELECT` list and in the `WHERE` clause. You can always do something like `select gid, secondc[array_position(cables, ?)], geom from...`

Comment: I try to do it, but the second argument can't be a character varying, even with a cast. I use 9.6.8

Comment: Frankly, I can't say anything without seeing the code. Maybe ask a new question with a code sample. Btw, the second argument is of type `anyelement` and the array is `text[]` so there shouldn't be problems with `varchar`.